# EntityFrameworkCore GroupBy Select FirstOrDefault() SystemInvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble with a LINQ query.

```
var cRecords = context.ClassificationRecords
   .GroupBy(p => p.ImageRecordId)
   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Created).FirstOrDefault())
   .ToList();
```

What I'm trying to do is get a list of the last dated classification record for each user. I'll include the user and some other stuff, but that's the stripped down version.

The problem is that the above is giving me an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (c.ImageRecordId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: ClassificationRecord
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Created)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

I've seen this query used in several places on here and other websites, so it should be working..?

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 with EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.11
The query is being ran inside a hangfire worker program, so not a Blazor server - not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: Could you show your ClassificationRecord class pls?

Comment: `var cRecords = context.ClassificationRecords.GroupBy(p => p.ImageRecordId).Select(g => new { ImageRecordId = g.Key, Last = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();` ?

Comment: EF Core has _extremely_ limited `GroupBy` translation compared to e.g. EF 6.x or EF 2.x (which converted to client processing automatically). I believe they have added some in EF Core 5 and plan to possibly add some more, but basically EF Core only translates `GroupBy` when it is directly equivalent to the SQL `GROUP BY` which means has aggregate functions in the result, etc. However there are modifications you can do to queries like this to get them to translate.

Comment: @mm8 EF Core 3.1 can't translate that either.

Comment: The extremely limited translation support goes for .NET 5 as well. It's only borderline usable at this point. EF6 classic is still MUCH better at translating virtually ANY "group by" query. Not only that, but any arbitrary open source library, like Linq2Db, manages to do a better job. With .NET 6 Microsoft intends to provide EF6 compatibility, but I really doubt it from what I see so far. Dunno why this question got voted down, it's frustrating how they can rewrite the same ORM like 4 times and not get it right. If not for Identity, I would still be using EF6 classic in .NET Core applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible work around is to modify your query into something EF 3.1 can translate - how efficient this will be depends on your database engine. I think this should work but you need the primary key to match the records:

```
var cRecords = context.ClassificationRecords
    .Where(c => c.PrimaryKey == context.ClassificationRecords.Where(c2 => c2.ImageRecordId == c.ImageRecordId)
                                                             .OrderByDescending(c2 => c2.Created)
                                                             .First().PrimaryKey)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: I'll need to do further testing, but so far - it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This query is not possible with EFC. After `GroupBy` you can select only grouping key or aggregation result. Faster query here is Window Functions usage which are not supported by EF.

So there is workaround:

```cs
var grouped =
   from c in ontext.ClassificationRecords
   group c by c.ImageRecordId into g
   select new 
   {
      ImageRecordId = g.Key,
      Created = g.Max(x => x.Created)
   };

var query =
   from g in grouped
   join c in context.ClassificationRecords 
     on new { g.Created, g.ImageRecordId } equals { c.Created, c.ImageRecordId }
   select c;

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: WIthout the primary key it is possible you get could more than one record from a group.